# Pass Query String to All Pages

Tags: javascript, query-string, google-tag-manager

I need a little bit of help here. I am a beginner at javascript and ran into some code in Google Tag Manager that is meant to pass the Query String to all pages. It works quite well, except for on one particular page of the site.

On that page, I have a bunch of quotes that users can scroll through. Whenever someone clicks the button to read the next quote on the carousel, the page refreshes (which we don't want).

Could some one help me adjust this code so that the page doesn't refresh in that particular use case?

I think the big issue is that the carousels are wrapped in `<a> </a>` tags.

```html
<script>
    for (var n = 0; n < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; n++) {
        var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[n].href;
      if (link.includes('?')) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('a')[n].href = link.concat('&' + {{Query String}});
      }
      else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('a')[n].href = link.concat('?' + {{Query String}});
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the URL of the read next quote button?

Comment: @imvain2 There isn't a URL of the read next quote button. This is the code I am seeing when I inspect the page: `<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-1389"><span class="label"></span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to sort ONLY links with the `href` argument.

```js
qstring = "x=1";
links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href]");

links.forEach(function(el){
  var link = el.href;
  if (link.includes('?')) {
    el.href = link.concat('&' + qstring);
   } else if (link[0] != "#") { {
   el.href = link.concat('?' + qstring);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://test.com/?xx">Test.com</a>
<a href="https://test.com/">Test.com</a>
<a href="https://test.com">Test.com</a>
<a name="a">Test.com</a>
```

Comment: Do I have to add in a list of all `href`s to get this to work? That seems like it would be a lot of work for every page of my website.

Comment: @Avenues_Q, just use the javascript that I provided with the only change is changing the query string. The links in my example are to show that the code is working.

Comment: That worked! I am running into a slight issue where the Query String is appended onto the URL twice so it looks like `www.test.com/?gclid=123&utm_source=Google&gclid=123&utm_source=Google`. Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: @Avenues_Q, are you still running the old code too?

Comment: No, I am not. I removed it. I have noticed this also tends to break Anchor Tags on the page as well. I have a button that links to the form at the top of the page and when I click it with this code, the anchor tag breaks and doesn't do anything. `#top-of-page`.

Comment: @Avenues_Q, I updated my answer to ignore any URL that starts with #.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help on this. I have run a couple more tests and wanted to let you know that the href is still breaking. Typically the anchor tag starts with `#`, but when this code is implemented, the anchor tag starts with `https://www.fakesite.com/?test=test?#anchor-tag-1`.

It seems that this code is swapping out the old anchor tag link and replacing it with the URL.